# Jest test fail with Emotion cache and Material UI datetime picker

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, emotion

I have the following strange error message, when I am running the test for a given file.
This error is not clear for me - and I am not sure how to handle it.

I am suspecting, that it may be some version mismatch between the newly installed @mui/x-date-picker package (added to the project lately) and the @emotion (@emotion-cache) package.

This is the error:

[image: Jest error]

These are my package versions:

[image: Packages]

Could you give me some direction on how to solve this? Or where/how to check the version problems/solutions?

Comment: Hi Hunor, I'm experiencing a similar issue. Were you able to fix your problem?